# Laravel Querying Views

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW orders_sales AS 
SELECT code, SUM(quantity) * SUM(sale_price) as product_total, shop_id
FROM `orders`
GROUP BY code, product_id
```

I am trying to query it like this:

```
$data = DB::table('orders_sales')->get();
```

I am getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
>   'pakishops2.orders.shop_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from
>   `orders_sales`)

I am able to query it in phpmyadmin like select * from orders_sales but it wont query with Laravel.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjxiR.png)

EDIT:

I have changed view name to view_saleorders, still no luck

Comment: does order have shop_id field ?

Comment: Why you kept same name for view and table ? Can you change it and check

Comment: I tried, changed name to view_saleorders, didn't work

Comment: try wrriting DB::query("select * from view_saleorders")->get(); and please keep different name for table and view

Comment: doesn't work either

Comment: is it working in phpmyadmin select * from view_saleorders ?

Comment: yes it is working there

Answer (score 0):

Try alternative now,

Create model with that name as laravel standard,

like

```
class ViewOrders extends Eloquent
```

Add namespaces required inside model if any.

then create class variable as

```
protected $table = 'your-view-name';
```

And now check data by getting like,

```
ViewOrders::all();
```

And check if you are getting data.

add `strict => false` in `config/database.php`.

If this is set to true then it'll add the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY when querying.

Alternative to be more specific with modes,

```
'modes' => [
    'NO_ZERO_DATE',
     'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
],
```

Comment: Nice trick but it didn't work. Same error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'pakishops2.orders.shop_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `view_saleorders`)

Comment: have you made 'strict' => false,
 in config/database.php. recheck my answer now

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `config/database.php` file and check if the option `strict` is set to true.

Set it to false and you query will work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to revive an old post, but your view is wrong. You need to match your columns to your `GROUP BY` clause.

Either change `shop_id` to `product_id`, or `product_id` to `shop_id`.

```
-- This is wrong. 
CREATE VIEW orders_sales AS 
SELECT code, SUM(quantity) * SUM(sale_price) as product_total, <!shop_id!>
FROM `orders`
GROUP BY code, <!product_id!>
```